# How does MD5 hashing not run out of hashes?

Tags: random, cryptography, md5

If I am not mistaken, MD5 is a hash 32 chars long.  If MD5 is only 32 chars long and we can make a string infinitely long, how is every hash different?  what is the upper limit of MD5 and how exactly is it completely unpredictable?

Comment: Would the downvoter please explain?  I now realize that it is a beginner question but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MD5, like all cryptographically secure hash functions, do not guarantee that every hash is different, just that is is highly unlikely and difficult to find two inputs that produce the same output.

MD5 is actually 16 8-bit bytes, 128-bits. Because of the short output (128-bits) and some internal issues, MD5 is no longer considered sufficient for most uses and generally SHA-256 is a good replacement.

Comment: @zaph: MD5 is AFAIR no longer considered to be a cryptographically secure hash function.

Comment: @dalearn: Yes, the "strength" of a hash function can be calculated how many money you would have to spend for finding a collision. For MD5 this is currently less that 1 USD (considering you are using a AWS cloud system).

Comment: @Robert Not all uses of cryptographically secure hash need to be resistant to finding a collision and in fact NIST still approves the use of MD5 for certain usages.

Comment: SHA-256 is a member of the SHA-2 family, see [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Answer (score 1):

You can have collisions.

Both:

- `d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab58712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89 55ad340609f4b30283e488832571415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbdf280373c5b d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e2b487da03fd02396306d248cda0 e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080a80d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f9652b6ff72a70`
- `d131dd02c5e6eec4693d9a0698aff95c 2fcab50712467eab4004583eb8fb7f89
  55ad340609f4b30283e4888325f1415a 085125e8f7cdc99fd91dbd7280373c5b
  d8823e3156348f5bae6dacd436c919c6 dd53e23487da03fd02396306d248cda0
  e99f33420f577ee8ce54b67080280d1e c69821bcb6a8839396f965ab6ff72a70`

Give the same hash:

```
79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4
```

Every hash can have collisions. It's just what are the chances of that happening?

[32-bit hashes have an even higher chance of colliding](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed):

- `cataract` collides with `periti`
- `roquette` collides with `skivie`
- `shawl` collides with `stormbound`
- `dowlases` collides with `tramontane`
- `cricketings` collides with `twanger`
- `longans` collides with `whigs`

Comment: Interestingly the first example is MD5, none of the others are MD5 or in the SHA* family. Many of the hash functuioins such as FNV-1, FNV-1, Murmur2, CRC32, etc are non-cryptographic hashes. Many non-cryptographic hashes allow frequent collisions by design as a tradeoff between speed and collision resistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, MD5 is a deterministic hashing algorithm, there is nothing random or randomized in MD5.

Of course if you apply MD5 to data there may be other data generating the same MD5 value. This is known als collision.

Comment: @dalearn It is not random because every time you hash the same value you get the same result.

Comment: but it can turn "password" into "286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4" so it appears random compared to the original.

Comment: It is not random, it is just a value. Don't mix up MD5 with compression or encryption. The result you get is not a password.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, but hash algorithms are "pseudorandom functions". He's not wrong to use the term 'random' here.